# Spring expression language - referencing variables

Tags: spring-el

I am able to do the following :-

```
ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
Expression exp = parser.parseExpression("'hi'.equals('hi')");
```

it evaluates to true.

Im failing at using variables in the expression  ? for example:

If i want to :
Case 1 :  use local variables

```
String str1 = "hi";
String str2 = "hi";
Expression exp = parser.parseExpression("str1.equals(str2)");
```

and Case2 : use field from a pojo :

```
Expression exp = parser.parseExpression("pojo1.getName().equals(pojo2.getName())");
```

How do i achieve case1 and 2 ? The above 2 examples are failing for me.. Case 1 evaluates to false and Case 2 throws an exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this:

##### Case 1:

```
String str1 = "hi";
String str2 = "hi";

StandardEvaluationContext evaluationContext = new StandardEvaluationContext();
evaluationContext.setVariable("str1", str1);
evaluationContext.setVariable("str2", str2);

ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
boolean result = parser.parseExpression("#str1 eq #str2").getValue(evaluationContext, Boolean.class);
// result will be true
// also "#str1 == #str2" can be used
```

##### Case 2:

```
StandardEvaluationContext evaluationContext = new StandardEvaluationContext();
evaluationContext.setVariable("pojo1Name", pojo1.getName());
evaluationContext.setVariable("pojo2Name", pojo2.getName());

ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
boolean result = parser.parseExpression("#pojo1Name eq #pojo2Name").getValue(evaluationContext, Boolean.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Case 1.

You have to register variables with evaluation context, then use `#str1` in the expression.

```java
    /**
     * Set a named variable within this evaluation context to a specified value.
     * @param name the name of the variable to set
     * @param value the value to be placed in the variable
     */
    void setVariable(String name, @Nullable Object value);
```

Case 2:

Use a `BeanExpressionResolver` wired up with the bean factory. If you implement `BeanFactoryAware`, use

```java
    @Override
    public void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory beanFactory) {
        this.beanFactory = beanFactory;
        if (beanFactory instanceof ConfigurableListableBeanFactory) {
            this.resolver = ((ConfigurableListableBeanFactory) beanFactory).getBeanExpressionResolver();
            this.expressionContext = new BeanExpressionContext((ConfigurableListableBeanFactory) beanFactory, null);
        }
    }
```

then call evaluate.

Beans are referenced with `@` - `@someBean.someMethod()`.